# C programming, solving C2073 error in structures?

Tags: c, visual-c++, data-structures

So, I'm new in this, and trying structures out... Error C2073 appeares..can someone help and give some advice?
I tried with FOR in main function to call functions "ispis" which is for printf only, and function "unos" which is for scanf so many times, how big is int "broj_knjiga". I tried to work with -> instead of . but I simply can't solve this problem(which is simple). Someone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ispis(struct knjiga *pt, int broj)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<broj; i++)
    {
    printf("\ID knjige: %d", &pt[i].ID_knjige);
    printf("\Autor knjige: %s", &pt[i].autor);
    printf("\Naslov knjige: %d", &pt[i].naslov);
    }
}

void unos(struct knjiga *pt, int broj)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<broj; i++)
    {
    printf("\nUnesite ID knjige: ");
    scanf("%d", &pt[i].ID_knjige);
    printf("\nUnesite autora knjige: ");
    scanf("%d", &pt[i].autor);
    printf("\nUnesite naslov knjige: ");
    scanf("%d", &pt[i].naslov);
    }
}

struct knjiga
{
    int ID_knjige;
    char autor[40];
    char naslov[20];
};

int main()
{
    struct knjiga *pt;
    int broj_knjiga;
    printf("Unesite koliko knjiga unosite: ");
    scanf("%d", &broj_knjiga);
    pt=(struct knjiga*)malloc(sizeof(struct knjiga)*broj_knjiga);
    unos(pt, broj_knjiga);
    ispis(pt, broj_knjiga);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, where's the definition of `struct knjiga`?

Comment: `struct knjiga {...};` move to top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C is compiled from the top-down. Structs only exist *below* their declarations. Moving your struct definition above the rest of your code will fix your problem.

```
knjiga myStruct1;  // invalid

struct knjiga
{
    int ID_knjige;
    char autor[40];
    char naslov[20];
};

knjiga myStruct2;  // valid
```